# Setting Cache-Control per file with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, cache-control

Is there a way to set the Cache-Control property per files in your ExpressJS app ? I would like a granular control over the caching of the files in my app... how can i achieve this ?
Whats the best practises in regards to Cache-Control ?

Comment: response.setHeader('Cache-Control', '...'); Can you explain more about which files need to set this? I'm guessing middleware is your best bet for controlling this, but need more info about how and when you'd like to control it.

Comment: The images, the javascripts, the css, basically all the files that are being served... I would like to have something similar to the app cache manifest, but i was thinking that setting headers was better for my case senario as the site in only to be viewed on a desktop...

Answer (score 8):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.match(/* some filter */)) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', ...)
  } else if (req.url.match(/* some filter */)) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', ...)
  }

  next()
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

No need to make it complicated.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is quite old but there is a simpler way to implement basic cache control on static files. Simply add an options object to the `express.static()` built-in middleware function like this:

```js
let options = {
    maxAge: "1d"
}

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', options))
```

This will enable cache-control for all of your static assets, by default. It would set the `Cache-Control` header to `public, max-age=86400`.